# JavaFxでの印刷に失敗する

Tags: java, javafx, 印刷

JavaFxにて、PrinterJobを使って以下のコードを実行しましたが、エラー（？）のような表示が出てうまく印刷ができませんでした（Google Chromeで開けませんでした）。
原因や解決策を教えていただきたいです。

**実行したコード**

```
AnchorPane node = new AnchorPane() ;
VBox vb = new VBox();
node.getChildren().add(vb);
for(int i = 0;i < 100;i++) {
    vb.getChildren().add(new Button("button-"+i));
}
System.out.println("EXPORT:"+node);
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
boolean doPrint = job.showPrintDialog(FBEApp.window);
if(doPrint) {
    System.out.println("印刷実行");
    job.printPage(node);
}else {
    System.out.println("印刷キャンセル");
}
System.out.println("----");
```

**コンソールに出た表示**

```
EXPORT:AnchorPane@30b4f8a8
印刷実行
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DFontFactory (file:/ *※非表示※* javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.graphics.jar) to method sun.font.FontUtilities.getCompositeFontUIResource(java.awt.Font)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DFontFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

**環境**
JRE ... javaSE-11
IDE ... eclipse
javafx ... 11.0.2

Answer (score 0):

まずはエラー(ではなく警告ですが)の内容から。。

だいたい以下のような意味だと思います。

> com.sun.prism.j2d.J2DFontFactoryからsun.font.FontUtilities.getCompositeFontUIResourceへの不正なリフレクションが発生しました。可能であればcom.sun.prism.j2d.J2DFontFactoryの開発者へレポートして下さい。不正なリフレクションは将来的に全面的に動作しなくなりますが、現在は--illegal-access=warnとすることで「警告」として動作します。

この警告については、マイクロソフトのサイトに詳細が記載されていました。引用すると。

> コマンド ライン オプション --illegal-access=warn を設定することをお勧めします。 Java 11 では、リフレクションを使用して JDK 内部 API にアクセスすると、不正なリフレクト アクセス警告が発生します。 既定では、最初の不正なアクセスに対してのみ警告が発行されます。 --illegal-access=warn を設定すると、不正な反射アクセス "ごとに" 警告が生成されます。 オプションが warn に設定された不正アクセスの場合、より多くのケースが見つかります。 ただし、重複する警告も多数表示されます。
> アプリケーションが Java 11 上で動作したら、Java ランタイムの今後の動作を模倣するように --illegal-access=deny を設定します。 Java 16 以降では、既定値は --illegal-access=deny です。

[参照サイト:https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/developer/java/fundamentals/transition-from-java-8-to-java-11](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/developer/java/fundamentals/transition-from-java-8-to-java-11)

なので、以下の条件で試してみることをお勧めします。

1. 実行するJDKのバージョンを下げて実行する。

Comment: 原因が判明して解決しました。どうやらPrinterJobでは印刷終了タイミングでendJobを呼び出す必要があるみたいです。（Bufferedreaderのflushのように）

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。直接の解放になっていなくて申し訳ないです。